# How we can stop bufio scanning at golang?

Tags: go, buffer

What's the best way to stop the below scanning?

```
     outputReader := io.MultiReader(outReader, errReader)
     scanner := bufio.NewScanner(outputReader)
     for scanner.Scan(){
        scanner.Text():
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean by best?  It either scans until EOF or you break whenever you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you are stuck in continuous loop and hitting `ENTER` wont help in exiting the loop of `scanner.Scan()`, then try `ctrl+Z` to exit loop.

Below is an example code for taking input from console and printing the duplicate lines.

```
func main() {
    counts := make(map[string]int)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("Accepting inputs")
    for scanner.Scan() {
        counts[input.Text()]++
    }
    // NOTE: ignoring potential errors from input.Err()
    fmt.Println("Printing output")
    for line, n := range counts {
        if n > 1 {
            fmt.Printf("Count: %d\t Line: %s\n", n, line)
        }
    }
}
```

Console Output:

```
Accepting inputs
Hi
hello
hi
Hi

^Z
Printing output
Count: 2         Line: Hi
```

We can see that just after pressing `ctrl+Z` the scanner.Scan() exited the loop.

Comment: `ctrl+D` for Mac and Linux

Answer (score 1):

[Scanner.Scan()](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Scan) will returns a bool. You don't need to do anything else, since the for loop will exit when it evaluates to `false` at the end of what it is scanning.

Comment: It scans remote host stdout and once it exited the loop I'm seeing the below at heap :

1: 4096 [4: 16384] @ 0x456015 0x59f097 0x565791 0x4735f1
# 0x59f097 bufio.(*Scanner).Scan+0x147 /usr/local/go/src/bufio/scan.go:197

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states:

> It returns false when the scan stops, either by reaching the end of the input or an error. After Scan returns false, the Err method will return any error that occurred during scanning, except that if it was io.EOF, Err will return nil.

Therefore, to stop scanning, you can break out of the loop manually after reading a line of text or you can wait until `false` is returned. If you need different functionality, you may want to use the `io.Reader` directly. The documentation for `io.Reader` states:

> If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.

Thus, the `Read` method will immediately return rather than blocking like `bufio.Scanner` would.

If you *do* want to use `bufio.Scanner` and want to stop it from reading, you must send an EOF through the `io.Reader` that was passed in. An example of this is shown below:

https://play.golang.org/p/ZF8bHX25KFq

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    r, w, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    go func() {
        w.WriteString("line of text\n")
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        w.Close()
    }()
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Printf("scanned \"%v\"\n", scanner.Text())
    }
    err = scanner.Err()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("done scanning")
}
```